# How to get jrebel, jetty, gradle and intellij idea working together

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, jetty, jrebel

I have installed JRebel plugin for Intellij Idea and my project is running with Jetty gradle plugin.

I run my project with "Run with JRebel", project perfectly runs, but hot swap which i expected is not working.

Does anybody have an understandable and detailed instruction how to set up Jrebel for work with jetty, gradle and intellij idea?

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to add [JRebel Agent](https://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/launch-from-command-line-jrebel-agent.html#jrebel-agent-recommended) as a vm argument into Jetty.

Depending on your environment:

```
Windows 64-bit JDK  jrebel64.dll
Windows 32-bit JDK  jrebel32.dll
Mac OS X 64-bit JDK libjrebel64.dylib
Mac OS X 32-bit JDK libjrebel32.dylib
Linux 64-bit JDK    libjrebel64.so
Linux 32-bit JDK    libjrebel32.so
```

You need to add `-agenthpath` argument in `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-agentpath:[c:\path\to\]lib\jrebel64.dll
```

2) You need to generate `rebel.xml` files for your projects in JRebel IDE plugin

**Right-click** on the project node in the **Project View** and select **JRebel > rebel.xml**. Alternatively, you can check projet in [JRebel Modules window](https://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/ide/intellij.html#tool-window)

3) You need to deploy(run) your projects into the Jetty with `rebel.xml` configuration files and when you make a code change in a .java file you need to generate new .class file. IntelliJ IDEA does not compile classes on save by default. Press **Ctrl+Shift+F9** to compile the current file, module or package (you can also find this command via **Build > Make Project**).